# Difference between external port and internal port in port forwarding?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

What is the difference between "external port" and "internal port" in port forwarding?

If internal port is the port no. to which server is listening to for a specific (eg: HTTP request) service request; then how do you define external port?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In layman's terms: Your router has a public IP address (the "external" address). Your router also provides the network devices within your home network with private IP addresses (the "internal" addresses).

With the port it's the same thing. For example: a HTTP request will be send to your router's IP to port 80 (the "external port") and will be forwarded by your router to a device on your LAN, to the "internal port" (and one of your private/internal IP addresses).

A rule you could define in your router would be for example:

80 (external port) --forward to--> 192.168.100.100:80 (internal ip/port)

This would mean that all requests that reach the router on port 80 (from the internet) will be forwarded to the device with the IP 192.168.100.100 on the same port (port 80).

Comment: Note that the external and internal port numbers _may_ be different.

Comment: yeah, thanks, that's correct, I didn't want to make the example too complicated. But also note, most but not all consumer grade routers give you this option.

Comment: @Albin "External Port" is the port that exist on the router? or the router just takes the note of port request  and forwards the request to internal ip and internal port (as per set portfowarding rule)?

Comment: @Albin Can I say like this => "Request received on router's public ip address and router's external port  will then be forwarded to the device on the LAN and to the device's internal port to complete the defined portforwarding rule? can I put this way? is it right if I explain port forwarding like this?

Comment: @Albin Or can I put this way? => " By default; All internet traffic’s http requests are received on your router’s external port 80"

Comment: @CodeStar more or less, but it's not just HTTP traffic, all traffic arriving at port 80 will forwarded (regardless of the protocol). But before you explain it to anybody I would recommend you read up on the topic e.g. [here about sockets](http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/tcpip-ports-sockets/)

Comment: @Albin Yeah I knew "HTTP" is one among many other services. But if I have to take an example I'll take "HTTP" for reference.

Comment: @CodeStar yes, for port 80 this is correct, since port 80 is the default port for HTTP

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct answer that is concise to the question being asked:

External is the port the outside device is going to try to connect to. Internal is the actual port open on the local device. They're usually the same, but might be different, depends on what you're trying to accomplish and what the server and client will let you customize. For example, if you have multiple web servers all listening on their own port 80 on the inside, you need to map different ports on the external side for each of them, because you can only have one port 80 on the external IP. If you just have one device that is telling you to forward port 1234, you can probably just set that on both.